# Plot Arbitray Slice of 3d points in Python

Tags: python

So I am a bit new to python and having a little trouble.

I am attempting to plot (project) a 3d data set onto an arbitrary plane. I can of course plot xy etc. but since my data has a particular orientation (all the points fall into an arbitrary orientated cylinder) I want project all the points onto a plane that slices that cylinder orthogonally and that plane would have a arbitrary orientation.

I am working with microseismic data if anyone is familiar with that and all the points are located around a wellbore with follows an arbitrary but fairly straight azimuth.

The data is in Cartesian coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Is your data in Cartesian coordinates like (x,y,z) or something else?

Comment: the data is in Cartesian coordinates(x,y,z), thanks

Comment: well, you could plot your points in 3d with Mayavi, or you could instead do the projection first to 2D (easier). if you have the unit norm 3D axis of the cylinder (c), you can project an arbitrary point x via: proj(x) = (x - (numpy.dot(x,c))*c)[:2]

Comment: sadly I do not have a unit norm axis...this is currently defined as another set of Cartesian coordinates

Comment: A separate set of points for the axis is fine, could just get a local difference vector or fit a line and use its parameters depending on accuracy of the points, what you want.  You could also find a line fit to the data you show and use that as the axis.